# Core 18: NetworkManager definitions do not support name globbbing

Tags: networking, ubuntu-core, netplan

I'm trying to install core18 with kernel 5.4. Everything boots fine, but when I get into the initial configuration screen and try to set up my networking, I am presented with this error:

```
Network configuration failed: 'ERROR: all-en: NetworkManager
        definitions do not support name globbing\n'
```

What does this mean? How do I fix it? I am not passing any network configuration through hooks or anything, what's the deal?

Answer (score 0):

This has been answered in the snapcraft forum: https://forum.snapcraft.io/t/core-18-networkmanager-definitions-do-not-support-name-globbbing/18125

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: Hey look, 'dat me! I did find a half-solution that kinda works, but this was never formally or fully solved. I'd also love some explanation for why this happens and how this works.

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of "completeness," I'll volunteer that  did find that moving my `configure` hook from my `kernel` snap to a `base-files` snap (so that it executes later in boot, I guess?) does allow the networking to at least function, however, I still get the stray IP address every now and then.

The hook is confidential, but I am basically overwriting the netplan and then applying it in a hook.